# Uninstall leads to 1603 error on windows 10 1703

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, advanced-installer

We have a Windows 10 1607 image with our app installed via Advanced Installer.

We then updated the app to a new version and the update worked as excepted.

However if we do the same procedure but with a Windows 10 1703 image, the upgrade of our app fails with the following error:

```
MSI (s) (58:B8) [16:12:02:846]: Note: 1: 2769 2: ShopInstallClass_x64 3: 1 
Error 1001. Error 1001. The specified service has been marked for deletion
Info 2769. Custom Action ShopInstallClass_x64 did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
CustomAction ShopInstallClass_x64 returned actual error code 1603 (note this 
may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (58:EC) [16:12:02:858]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035    
MSI (s) (58:EC) [16:12:02:860]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (58:EC) [16:12:02:860]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 16:12:02: InstallExecute. Return value 3
```

The custom action above refers to a windows service which is being uninstalled and then reinstalled with the new update. I tried putting a stop service and even a stop process to see if that would work (possibly handles left open) and the installer still did not work.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the custom action has crashed, I assume you know that. Without showing more of the log it's also not clear where in the upgrade it's happening, if in fact you're referring to a major upgrade when you say "update". In a major upgrade there's an install of the new product and an uninstall of the older one - where is this crash happening in that sequence? It's also possible that your ShopInstall class is an installer class to install a service, which isn't necessary because Windows Installer has ServiceInstall actions for that.

Having said that, the message "The specified service has been marked for deletion" implies that the code is trying to do something to a disabled service. So it looks like a previous uninstall of the service has been attempted, and the service did not shut down or stop correctly. In that situation Windows will mark the service disabled and then a reboot will finally delete it. In the meantime if something tries to do something with that service it will fail with the "pending deletion" error. So you'd have to go back to whatever uninstall was attempted and why it failed to first stop, and then uninstall the service.

Comment: If it is the installer that is deleting the service, it may just be a matter of doing things in the right order: you have to stop the service, and you may need to wait for it to actually stop, before deleting it.  I don't recall the details offhand, but I have noticed that Windows 10 behaves differently towards services that have a pending delete than Windows 7 does.  It wouldn't be too surprising if it has changed again in 1703.

Comment: @PhilDW : I did not write the installer and am trying to help out so forgive me for not explaining it as I should. Yes you are right, the product is uninstalled and then reinstalled with the new product (using the same key). I did notice that there were some .jar files that did not seem be releases (our app uses a .net to Java bridge). I'll try to understand more on this but for now is there a way to KILL the service if it is not uninstalled properly or to kill it then install so there are no jar/handle lying around?